# Update component in a different window/tab without manually refreshing it

Tags: forms, jsf-2, primefaces, commandbutton

I have different pages with different layouts, for example index.xhtml and user.xhtml, each page has it's own template. If I make a change in user.xhtml I want to update a datatable in index.xhtml.

index.xhtml:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<ui:composition template="/template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="body">
 <h:form id="indexFormId">
         <p:dataTable id="datalist" value="#{userController.items}"var="item" widgetVar="userWidget">
 -----datatable columns and rows with user data------
 </p:datatable>
 </h:form>
```

user.xhtml:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<ui:composition template="/templateB.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="body">
 <h:form>
 <p:commandButton value="Modify User" actionListner="some action" update=":thisForm, :indexFormId"/>
 </h:form>
```

So when I close user.xhtml i see index.xhtml datatable updated without ask for a manually refresh. Is it possible ? There are some way to achieve this ? I see that there is a way to do that with the same template using .

Comment: Close means browser close event or session invalidate(logout) ?

Comment: I have one browser session with 2 or more tabs opened. So when I modify something in a tab I want to update some values in the others. Is this possible ? I understand that one way is possible if the 2 tabs have the same layout. @BholaVishwakarma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [PrimeFaces User Guide](http://www.primefaces.org/documentation) on the following options.

- `p:poll` component (periodic server polling).
- PrimeFaces Push (a more versatile solution on top of Atmosphere framework).

Comment: I understand that one way is to use websocket or similar. Thanks